# Environment.GetFolderPath returning incorrect address

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, environment, special-folders

Why does

```
string AssignmentTypesFilename = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\SchoolDayManager\AssignmentTypes.txt";`
```

always return

```
"C:\\\Users\\\Travis Michael\\\Documents\\\SchoolDayManager\\\AssignmentTypes.txt"
```

instead of

```
"C:\Users\Travis Michael\Documents\SchoolDayManager\AssignmentTypes.txt"?
```

Comment: Of course, **it doesn't**. I just tested it to make sure. Something else is wrong; not enough information to tell what it is.

Comment: I was trying to make sure the file existed and it would always return false so I tried to check to see what the string was and it would always be the first string I gave. I eventually got so frustrated I restarted my computer and now it is working. I have never had this problem before, that's why it was so puzzling to me.

Comment: An OpenFileDialog is really the best solution. What if I want to place my files in a directory other than `SchoolDayManager`? You have the right idea with not hard-coding the path to the documents folder, but I'd take it one step further and make all of this completely configurable by the user. I've definitely never had that problem before either, and I can't repro it.

Answer (score 3):

How do you look at the string? Through the debugger's watch window? In the debugger, strings are sometimes escaped before they are displayed. Try displaying it to the user, through

```
Console.WriteLine(AssignmentTypesFilename);
```

or if using a WinForm GUI:

```
MessageBox.Show(AssignmentTypesFilename);
```

It should be displayed correctly then.